# Heroku FATAL: role is not permitted to log in / database de-provisioned

Tags: heroku

I was testing an app on Heroku and out of the blue the dev database went offline. postgres.heroku.com has the following information on the database:

```
Statistics
Plan    Dev
Status  
Data Size   0 B
Tables  7
PG Version  ?
Created     February 27, 2013 19:38
```

The logs say `FATAL:  role "-removed-" is not permitted to log in`.

The heroku docs have the error but it doesn't really help:

```
FATAL: role “role-name”…

FATAL: role "u8akd9ajka" is not permitted to log in (PG::Error)

This occurs when you have de-provisioned a starter tier database but are still trying to connect to it. To resolve:

    If required, provision a new database via heroku addons:add heroku-postgresql
    Use heroku pg:promote HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_<new-database-color> to promote it, making it the primary database for your application.
```

How does a database get de-provisioned? As far as I can tell I didn't do anything to the database, it just went offline.

I can use the promote command on the database successfully (`heroku pg:promote HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_ROSE`) but it stays in the same state. If I run `heroku pg:info` I get `Resource not found`

I can add a new database and start over but I want to know if I can bring the database back to life (the prospect of this happening in production is scary).

Answer (score 1):

Heroku had an issue just about the time you show your database created: https://status.heroku.com/incidents/498 ... Perhaps there was a problem with your database related to that.

When you're in production you're on a different tier than the free accounts; I personally haven't had an issue with Heroku production apps in 3 years.

Comment: Could be but it's strange it was working yesterday. Anything I can try to get the DB back? (as an exercise)

Comment: You can open a ticket with Heroku support.  I'm sure they'd be helpful in getting an answer.  I'm not sure what the SLA for the free accounts is though.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue when I was using Heroku pipeline with Node JS + Heroku Postgress.

I have resolved this by checking if the DATABASE_URL on **staging** is the same as with the **Review App**

[image]

In the review apps, go to **More Settings** => Find and click on **Config Vars** to check DATABASE_URL if it's the same as with staging

Answer (score -1):

This happens when we delete/de-provision database and forgot to remove CONFIG VARS (ENV variables).(Sometimes CONFIG vars don't get autoremoved)

Try Clearing

> "DATABASE_URL"

variable from

> App Settings tab > Config Variables

and after that reprovision postgres DB.

Comment: Heroku does not allow deletion of the DATABASE_URL config variable. It is deleted after PostGreSQL is deleted.